# Curl slow then times out on status of website

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code to check the status of a website, this works great on most sites but having issues with others

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_exec($curl);
        $code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($code == 200) {
            echo "<h3>Up!</h3>";
        } else {
            echo "";
        }
```

the following sites it works perfectly `ebay.com, stackoverflow.com`

but not `google.com, blackberry.com and facebook.com.`

it goes real slow and times out.

I have read the error log and this is what i find

```
 mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds,

 Premature end of script headers:
```

Comment: Have you checked with HTTPS?

Comment: yes, and still slow and times out

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code, worked fine for me. I just changed $ch and $rch with $curl

Comment: @AliMasudianPour was it slow? i am still having the same problem .

Comment: No, For all url's you showed in your question it says Up!

Comment: I set $url="http://google.com"; for example. Have you checked your $_POST to see whether the URL sent correctly or not>

Comment: Apart from the missing bracket at the end of your code, everything seems to be fine. I was not able to reproduce your timeout problem. Are you sure there is nothing else in your code that times out?

Comment: i think i must be a server issue, im going to look it that now.